# Nivo slider displaying numbers instead of background image

Tags: javascript, nivo-slider

I am running intro a pretty strange situation. I've added a nivo slider on a site but when I turn controlnav on the slide navigator is composed of numbers. The thing is I'd like to use bullets instead of those numbers. I've tried to add text-indent:-9999px but that doesn't work.  I've used Nivo before plenty of times, this is the first time it's happening. The script is new and as far as I can see there is no scripting or css issue that might be causing it

Site is here: http://minimaltheme01.brideappeal.com/

Any idea why this might be happening?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default nivo slider displays the numbers. To get them to be restyled and show bullets instead of the numbers you can use a theme or you could optionally write your own css to style them.

Check the [documentation](http://docs.dev7studios.com/jquery-plugins/nivo-slider#jumpNav-6) to see how to include a theme.

You will need to alter to html a little.

Check out these 2 js fiddles for (rough) examples of with and without the theme.

http://jsfiddle.net/cyZH2/ - without

http://jsfiddle.net/8Tafp/ - with

In the default-theme css file, it includes the following styles that display the links as bullets.

```
.theme-default .nivoSlider a {
    border:0;
    display:block;
}

.theme-default .nivo-controlNav {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 0;
}
.theme-default .nivo-controlNav a {
    display:inline-block;
    width:22px;
    height:22px;
    background:url(bullets.png) no-repeat;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    border:0;
    margin: 0 2px;
}
.theme-default .nivo-controlNav a.active {
    background-position:0 -22px;
}
```

Comment: I also experienced this problem and I am using default theme and dark theme, none of them changes the numbers into bullets

Comment: in your second Jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/8Tafp/ - with. I don't see the bullets nor number

Comment: @Citra45Abadi thanks for the heads up. The domain that was hosting the image assets has been removed. When I have time later today. I will update the fiddle.